# Added swagger UI on my express app but POST req body is not editable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

Hi Below is swagger code for API endpoint for post request. I can see the BODY in swagger UI but when I click on try it now I cannot edit request body.
Below is my code

```
/**
* @swagger
* /foods:
*   post:
*     summary: Creates a food item
*     consumes: application/json
*     parameters:
*       - in: body
*         type: object
*         properties:
*           ITEM_ID:
*               type: string
*           ITEM_NAME:
*               type: string
*           ITEM_UNIT:
*               type: string
*           COMPANY_ID:
*               type: string
*     responses:
*       201:
*         description: Created
*       400:
*         description: Bad Request
*       500:
*         description: Internal Server Error
*/
app.post('/foods',[check('ITEM_ID').not().isEmpty().trim(), check('ITEM_NAME').not().isEmpty().trim(), check('ITEM_UNIT').not().isEmpty().trim(), check('COMPANY_ID').not().isEmpty().trim()], async (req,res) => {
    let connection; 
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array()});
    }
    else{
        try {
            connection = await pool.getConnection();
            var itemID = req.body.ITEM_ID;
            var itemName = req.body.ITEM_NAME;
            var itemUnit = req.body.ITEM_UNIT;
            var companyID = req.body.COMPANY_ID;

            var sql = `INSERT INTO foods (ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_UNIT, COMPANY_ID) VALUES ('${itemID}', '${itemName}', '${itemUnit}','${companyID}')`;
            var rows = await connection.query(sql);
            res.status(201).json(req.body)
        }
        catch(err){
            res.status(400).send(err.message);
        } finally{
            if(connection){
                return connection.release();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Below is my swagger init code where I set the URL and other settings. Is there way I can make the req body editable. My POST api works fine with postman.

```
const options = {
    swaggerDefinition: {
      info: {
        title: 'API',
        description:'Sample DB CRUD Operations API',
        version: '1.0.0',
      },
      host: '<host>:3000',
      basePath:'/'
    },
    apis: ['./server.js'], // files containing annotations as above
  };
  
const specs = swaggerJsDoc(options);

app.use('/docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(specs));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Body parameters need a `name` and also require the `schema` keyword to wrap the type definition. Replace

```
*       - in: body
*         type: object
*         properties:
*           ITEM_ID:
*               type: string
*           ...
```

with

```
*       - in: body
*         name: body
*         schema:
*           type: object
*           properties:
*             ITEM_ID:
*               type: string
*             ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if your project included swagger-ui-express check your yaml.

check point.
https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/171